# Calculating the expectation of the $n^{\text{th}}$ moment of a poisson variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, poisson-distribution, expected-value

Suppose I have a random variable $X \sim \text{Pois}(\lambda)$. I want to calculate $E[X^{n}]$, in terms of $n$. Here's what I did:

$$E[x^{n}] = \sum_{x = 0}^{\infty} x^{n} \cdot \frac{\lambda^{x} e^{-\lambda}}{x!}$$

$$= \sum_{x = 0}^{\infty} x \cdot x^{n - 1} \cdot \frac{\lambda \cdot \lambda^{x-1}e^{-\lambda}}{x!} $$

$$= \lambda \sum_{x = 0}^{\infty}  x^{n - 1} \cdot \frac{\lambda^{x - 1} e^{-\lambda}}{(x - 1)!}$$

$$= \lambda \sum_{y = -1}^{\infty} (y + 1) \frac{e^{-\lambda}\cdot \lambda^{y}}{y!}$$

$$= \lambda E(X + 1)^{n - 1}.$$

Above, I set $y = x - 1$. Is this correct? Are the bounds on my sum correct? or should it go from $n = 0$ to $\infty$? I know that the answer is right, but i want to check my work, please.

**EDIT: Attempt #2**

Ok, so the sum should be from $0$ to $\infty$. Is this correct?

$$\mathbb{E}[X^{n}] = \sum_{x = 0}^{\infty} x^{n} \cdot \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{x}}{x!} $$

$$= \lambda \sum_{x = 1}^{\infty} x^{n - 1} \cdot \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{x - 1}}{(x - 1)!}$$

I could change the sum from $x = 0 $ to $x = 1$ because the term becomes $0$ for the $x = 0$ index. Now let $y = x - 1$:

$$\lambda \cdot \sum_{y = 0}^{\infty}(y + 1)^{n - 1} \cdot \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{y}}{y!} $$

$$ = \lambda \cdot E[(X + 1)^{n - 1}].$$

Comment: It should be from $n=0$ to $\infty$

Comment: @sc_ No, $n$ (the exponent in what you're calculating) is fixed, $x$ (the value of the random variable) goes from $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: If you try to describe the n'th moment in terms of previous moments, then you encounter an AR model of degree (n-1) [a difference equation of degree n-1] with all previous moments unknown and solving it is brutal if possible. They can be described in terms of Touchard polynomials but i can't remember how, :)) sorry dude!

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks for pointing that out. What I actually meant was that the variable over which the summation is carried out goes from $0$ to $\infty$ but wrote $n$ by mistake.

Comment: Okay, can you check again? @sc_

Comment: Yes! It is now correct.

Answer (score 1):

Moments of Poisson distribution can be obtained using this recursive formula:

$$m_n (\lambda) = \mathbb{E}\{x^n\} = e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k^n \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} \Rightarrow \frac{\partial \; m_n(\lambda)}{\partial \lambda} = -e^{\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k^n \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} + e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k^(n+1) \frac{\lambda^{(k-1)}}{k!} = -m_n(\lambda)+\frac{1}{\lambda}m_{n+1}(\lambda) \Rightarrow m_{n+1}(\lambda) = \lambda\times\left( m_n(\lambda) + m^{'}_n(\lambda) \right)$$